# Error using function rle()

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe in R called pxlast, for example to access to the 5 column I use pxlast[[5]].

```
[1] 259.55 259.55 265.21 269.40 278.23 283.63 288.51 289.84 284.83 280.51 289.76 289.38 294.10  -1.00  -1.00  -1.00
 [17] 300.30 303.86 311.65 303.29 296.44 295.13 297.22 294.60 299.65 290.23 295.80  -1.00  -1.00  -1.00 298.56 299.25
 [33] 287.37 290.06 281.71 287.66 290.16 280.31 281.51 293.69 292.25 293.73 294.60 291.36 283.81 288.65 288.29  -1.00
 [49]  -1.00  -1.00 293.25 293.54 277.41 268.08 267.01 270.63 267.25 254.73 266.59 266.73 278.34 282.03 289.63 282.40
 [65] 289.59 289.54 291.31 290.85 295.60 290.72 288.25 288.00 293.98 297.11 290.00 278.35 270.61 274.89 267.80 276.32
 [81] 279.05 289.07 285.87 293.36 293.18 294.76 295.77 296.35 290.23 297.61 296.93 293.31 290.06 289.98 287.29 282.07
 [97] 275.89 270.92 273.68 270.85 280.05 279.64 284.83 288.91 294.85 296.91 297.94 301.66 303.05 298.72 303.46 298.22
[113] 304.92 309.59 316.07 318.05 318.86 318.09 317.84 318.04 337.08 346.89 345.36 350.96 354.65 361.06 354.53 352.63
[129] 352.83 351.45 351.38 361.47 365.13 367.11 371.42 364.37 368.83 372.12 375.10 381.97 384.47 388.67 388.61 386.73
[145] 392.16 388.55 383.86 389.50 379.83 381.37 392.27 387.79 388.61 388.01 394.23 401.78 414.70 421.23 427.77 436.23
[161] 423.86 398.80 419.00 413.60 400.77 416.78 412.58 405.90 404.30 405.65     NA
```

As you can see there are repated values for example -1 values.

I want to return the values and indexes which are repeated more than X times, for example the values that are repeated more than 3 times.

This is my code for doing that.

```
runs = rle(pxlast[[5]])
pxlast[[5]][runs$lengths > 2]
```

The result is:

```
[1] 294.10 299.65 294.60
```

This result should be the first repeated element from my vector, as you can see the values are incorrect.

Why?

I have been testing and rle function is returning on my runs variable the following.

```
[1] 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [59] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[117] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

As you can see the function groups that values that are the same, so for example the first "2 value" that appears means that the 2 first numbers are the same, that is to say this vector is grouping if the number are the same, so I can't use it on my vector to return my repeated values because it doesn't match which the total amount of indixes.

If it were in the following way , for example to the 25 first lines, I could use it.

```
[1] 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Because you keep the total sum of the indices.

Any idea to solve it?

Comment: The reason is that `run$lengths` ouptut is not the same length therefor you need `i1 <- run$values <- runs$lengths > 2; pxlast[[5]][inverse.rle(run)]`

Comment: Yeah, I know, if I could create a vector based on the other as the example I put in my explication, I could do it as I am doing.

Comment: What I meant is that you cannot subset the original vector based on the `lengths` unless you replicate because these are of different lengths

Comment: Yeah I know, If i could replicate values of that vector, for example 2, for 2 2 or 3 for 3 3 3 I could use it because they would have the same dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to extract the values based on the `rle` index

```
runs <- within.list(rle(pxlast[[5]]),  {
                 i1 <- lengths > 2
                 values <- values[i1]
                 lengths <- lengths[i1]})

inverse.rle(runs)
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
v1 <- c(2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5)
runs <- within.list(rle(v1),  {i1 <- lengths > 2
                 values <- values[i1]
               lengths <- lengths[i1]})
inverse.rle(runs)
#[1] 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible way:

```
df<-data.frame(lengths=as.numeric(runs$lengths),values=as.numeric(runs$values))
df[df[,"lengths"]>2,]
   lengths values
13       3     -1
25       3     -1
43       3     -1
```